# GUI Workflow command

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am developing a GUI in Matlab and I would like to know which is the workflow when you click a button. Being more specific, I would like to know 'what happens' when I click a button, because its callback is not triggered.

Comment: You mean the standard buttons, like zoom and so right? Please write down something if you find out what happens. I would be interested too. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GUIDE` for developing, every time you add a button to your `GUI` a chunk of code is generated:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

This function is called every time you push the said button. So, if you need something to be executed when you click the button you just need to add the lines of code you want to execute below that generated chunk of code. For example, imagine you have an `edit text` variable called `edit1` with value

```
edit1 = 'hello';
```

If you want to interact with it you need to call `handles`, but first you need to create a global variable:

```
%set the current figure handle to main application data
setappdata(0,'figureHandle',gcf);
%set the handles to figure's application data
setappdata(gcf,'EDIT1',handles.edit1);
```

Then, in the callback function of your button you need write the following:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
figureHandle = getappdata(0,'figureHandle');
EDIT1 = getappdata(figureHandle,'EDIT1 ');
new_string = 'updated string';
set(EDIT1, 'String', new_string);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but this was not what I was looking for.
I mean if, once you have your GUI developed, it is possible to know with a Matlab command the workflow, how the information is passed among the functions. Like the 'profiler', but for interactions.

Comment: you mean something like this: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html ?

Comment: Not exactly, but could be useful.
I would need a command that offers you a graphic with arrows or similar, showing when a function is called and where it goes and so on.

Comment: @YisasL Just wondering... Where did you ever see such a functionality?